# React TypeScript: react-markdown no overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown

I'm happy to move to another library if needed but react-markdown seems to have good reports, however, im getting the below error when I try to use it with typescript in a functional component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Markdown from 'react-markdown';

const Home: React.FC = () => {

  const getMarkdown = async () => {
    const markdown = await fetch('../markdown/home.md');
    const text = await markdown.text();
    return text;
  }
  const src = getMarkdown();

  return (    
      <div className='max-width'>
          <span className='body'>
            <Markdown source={src} />
          </span>
      </div>
  );
}

export { Home };
```

the error I get is

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<ReactMarkdownProps>): ReactMarkdown', gave the following error.
    Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReactMarkdownProps, context?: any): ReactMarkdown', gave the following error.
    Type 'Promise<Response>' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2769
```

Comment: `src` is a promise not a string.

Comment: Thank's Joseph I added an await and got more errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react hooks

```
const Home = () => {
const [text, setText] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
     async function getText() {
         const markdown = await fetch('../markdown/home.md');
         const text = await markdown.text();
         setText(text);
     }
     getText();
  }, []);
  return (<div className='max-width'>
          <span className='body'>
            <Markdown source={text} />
          </span>
      </div>);
}
```

Comment: This certainly cleared the error but the markdown doesn't render

Comment: just verify if `text` is getting updated with markdown contents.

Comment: When I log text I dont see any of the content from home.md instead i see html from the site <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta name="viewport" content="

Comment: My guess is that path to markdown file might be wrong, try with some online markdown file ( CORS might be an issue)

Comment: If I move the markdown folder to ./public then link to it, it works, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :)